# Do Quip live apps still support the creationUrl param?

Tags: quip, liveapps

In your live apps documentation you mention being able to [add a live app via a link](https://mode.quip.com/dev/liveapps/documentation#initialization) in a quip document. I can't however find a way to do that in a quip document so I am unclear how or if I can use the creationUrl param when initializing a quip live app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It wasn't obvious but I was able to find the documentation in the [App Manifest](https://mode.quip.com/dev/liveapps/documentation#app-manifest) section to answer this questions. The `intercept_url_patterns` field is required to allow links to open quip live apps.